# How close to the launch site at Kennedy Space Center does a press badge allow?

Tags: launch, observation, kennedy-space-center

How much closer than Bananna Creek Viewing Area can a press badge get me to the launch site at Kennedy space center? Or any other way to get closer?

Comment: If you are an astronaut on the flight you get pretty close.

Comment: Marry an astronaut and you can watch from the top of the VAB.

Answer (score 1):

The Press Site is approximately 3.2 miles to Pad 39A, while the Banana Creek site is roughly 3.9 miles.

Comment: Welcome to *Space*!  Can you identify the source of your information?